# How to use a JavaScript Material Design library in ReScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, reason, rescript

I am trying to use the [`material-ui` library](https://material-ui.com/) in a Rescript/React app. The code below will show a button:

```js
@module("@material-ui/core/Button") external button: string = "default"

@react.component
let make = () => {
     <button > {React.string("Hello")} </button>
}
```

The button shown is basic and I cannot change basic properties like `variant="contained"` or  `color="primary"` as they aren't recognised. I tried to change the `string` type, in the first line, to a type from the TypeScript `@material-ui/core/Button` file, but it didn't work. I tried to use `%%raw()` and `%raw()`, but they are very limited. I could not work with the objects they returned as ReScript doesn't know their types. Also, I could not call `React.useEffect()` using `%raw()` (as it doesn't return anything)  inside the `make` function.

In TypeScript, I can use objects and call functions without having type information about them.

Is there a way to do the same thing in ReScript or do I have to add all the typing information myself (if I want to use a library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly use a library like we do in typescript. Rescript has a very strong type system and does not have `any` type.

You can use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@jsiebern/bs-material-ui for Rescript material ui bindings. You can check for bindings or rescript libraries [here](https://rescript-lang.org/packages). Only if there is no bindings available already, you may have to write it.

Answer (score 0):

The binding signature is incorrect. Try this:

```
module Button = {
  @module("@material-ui/core/Button") @react.component
  external make: (~variant=option<[ | #outline | #contained ]>=?, ~children) => React.element = "default"
}


@react.component
let make = () => {
     <Button variant=#outline> {React.string("Hello")} </Button>
}
```

Comment: It didn't work:"@rescript/react": "0.10.3", "bs-platform": "9.0.2"
Syntax error!
  3 │   external make: (~variant=option<[ | #outline | #contained ]>=?, ~children) => React.element = "default" Did you forget a `:` here (in place of the first =)? It signals the start of a type

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://rescript-material-ui.cca.io/) you can find bindings for material-ui.
[Here](https://github.com/cca-io/rescript-material-ui) you can find github repo

> `rescript-material-ui` provides ReScript bindings for the Javascript based UI library MUI (formerly MaterialUi).

> The bindings are automatically generated by utilizing the documentation generation scripts of the original package. These rely on a mix of code & code annotations and are not always 100% accurate.

> This will directly translate into the bindings. If you come across a missing prop on a component or a misbehaving component, please feel free to open an issue.